# Наибольший элемент

Tags: c++

Дан массив. Выведите значение наибольшего элемента в массиве. Вот с такой элементарной задачей я столкнулся, при изучении плюсов.

*ВХОДНЫЕ ДАННЫЕ*

**Программа получает на вход число N, в следующей строке дано N чисел — элементы массива.**

*ВЫХОДНЫЕ ДАННЫЕ*
**Программа должна вывести значение наибольшего элемента массива.**

*пример*

ввод
5

1 2 3 2 1

вывод

3

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n, a, maxx;
    cin >> n;
    vector <int> num;
    maxx = pow(-10, 9);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> a;
        num.push_back(a);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (num[i] > maxx) {
            maxx = num[i];
        }
    }
    cout << maxx;

}
```

Программа проходит 17 из 21 одного теста и я никак не могу понять где ошибка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
maxx = pow(-10, 9);
```

так делать очень нехорошо, в тесте могут дать число и меньше -1.000.000.000

используйте `std::numeric_limits<int>::min()` или `INT_MIN` или `0xFFFFFFFF`

а касательно вашего кода можно сделать и попроще:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    cin >> a;
    num.push_back(a);
}

int maxx = num[0]; // первый элемент - максимальный, а дальше - посмотрим
for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
    if (num[i] > maxx) {
        maxx = num[i];
    }
}
cout << maxx;
```

**P.S.**

и я бы учел (для теста), если вводят `n < 1` :)